# Imported function is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In file1.js:

```
const doSomething = () => {
  console.log('yay');
};

export { doSomething }; 
//simplified, not using export default due to multiple exports
```

In file2.jsx:

```
import { doSomething } from './file1.js';

doSomething(); //undefined
```

Been trying to solve this for a while now. Trying to import this method from one class and add it as an onClick for a component, but it's always undefined. Help would be appreciated

edit1: fixed import in simplified code

Comment: explain in detail with code

Comment: @VaibhavS The code that's already been posted looks like a complete repro of the problem to me. What do you think is missing?

Comment: The code provided is just a simplified version of the actual code. There is a function in one file, I wish to export that function and call it in another file.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the cause of your problem in the code you posted. See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/v6vp81657l
Is that different than what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Nope, that's pretty much the same. The function I'm trying to export just isn't getting exported (console logging what was imported shows 2 out of 3 exported functions, the missing one being the one I want)

Comment: Weird. Are you exporting something else from that file? Do you have default exports in the same file?

Comment: what do you use as bundler and with what config (webpack, browserify etc...) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.
import file1.js in file2.js like this

`import * as demo  from './file1.js';`

and call your function  like this

`demo.doSomething()`

Comment: This got me a little further. Looks like my method isn't actually being exported. Doing a console.log(demo) returns the 2 other functions I'm exporting, but not the desired one.

Comment: try this `export const doSomething = () => {
    console.log('yay');
};`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are calling the functions which will not return anything.

if you do `console.log(doSomething())`, 
you will get logs like this.

```
yay //you called a functions its executed
undefined // you called a function which will not return anything
```

first log is from `doSomething` `file1.js` file.

second log is from `file2.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

Change Function Expression to Function Declaration. Function Declaration is create's by interpretor **before** application is started.

Function Expression creates a variable that is equal to undefined.

- If `file2` execute before `file1`, doSomething variable is undefined.
- If `file1` execute before `file2`, doSomething variable is link to function.

Answer (score -2):

fil1.js

```
export const doSomething = () => {
    console.log('yay');
};
```

file2.js

```
import { doSomething } from './file1.js';

doSomething();
```

Comment: The import path is correct, that's just a mistake in my simplified repro. Mb

Comment: just now i notice you trying import into jsx file. maybe it's different

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.